# Probability of getting first consecutive 6 on roll k

Tags: probability, random-variables, dice

Let $X$ be the random variable that counts the number of dice throws (fair and 6-sided) till we throw two consecutive $6$. For example, taking the rolls w = $(1,4,3,6,6) \ \  X(w) = 3$. I am trying to find the probability of $P(X=k)$ for all $k$. I know how to do this by using Markov-Chains but i am trying to generalize and find a pattern without using those.

My work so far:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/d30e4.png

Comment: Well, there's a simple recursive method...not sure if you'd say that was equivalent to Markov chains or not.

Comment: Sketch:  let $p_1(n)$ denote the probability that you haven't tossed $66$ in the first $n$ tosses AND that the $n^{th}$ toss is not a $6$, let $p_2(n)$ be the same except that the $n^{th}$ toss is a $6$.  Then we get $p_1(n+1)=\frac 56\times (p_1(n)+p_2(n))$ and $p_2(n+1)=\frac 16\times p_1(n)$ and your desired probability is $\frac 1{36}\times p_1(n)$.  This can be solved, as it resolves to a standard linear recursion with constant coefficients.

Comment: The same method i used for markov chains but i was able to solve it with your sketch. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use uniform probability and use a recursion similar to Fibonacci numbers(for example it would be exactly Fibonacci numbers if you have a coint and you search for the number of throws till you throw TT): start to work out the number of possible strings of dice throws from the end to the start. You know that if X outputs $k$ then the two $6$ appeared in the $(k+1)$th and $(k+2)$th positions and so there must have been a number $\omega(k)\in\{1,...,5\}$ in the $k$th positions (so you have five possibilities to build a string by adding this element. If you keep on with this reasoning for example $\omega(k-1)\in\{1,...,6\}$ (so you have 6 possibilities by adding this element). Now you have to differ between 2 cases for $\omega(k-2)$ :you have $6$ possibilities if $\omega(k-1)\in\{1,...,5\}$ or you have $5$ possibilities if $\omega(k-1)=6$. So the total number of new possibilities is ...